# Get value between from a private key using regex

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am receiving a private key something like this:-

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpQIBAAKCAQEA3Tz2mr7SZiAMfQyuvBjM9Oi..Z1BjP5CE/Wm/Rr500P
DtkpjGHQzPF6vOe907y5NQLvVFGXUq/FIJZxB8k..fJdHEm2M4=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I want the data after the last ----- in first line and first ----- of the last line such that the data of the matching group looks like this:-

```
MIIEpQIBAAKCAQEA3Tz2mr7SZiAMfQyuvBjM9Oi..Z1BjP5CE/Wm/Rr500P
DtkpjGHQzPF6vOe907y5NQLvVFGXUq/FIJZxB8k..fJdHEm2M4=
```

This is what I tried and definitely not getting what I want

```
(?=[-]*(?=[A-Z]*(?=[-])))(.*)(?=[-]*(?=[A-Z]*(?=[-])))
```

Can you please help me get this one correct.

Comment: Wouldn't this be easier with basic string operations rather than regex?

Comment: @Aran-Fey yes it is. I was playing around with regex but was unable to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
-{3,}\n([\s\S]*?)\n-{3,}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/440r5a/1). The value you need is in Group 1. If `\R` (any line break sequence pattern) is supported use it instead of `\n`.

**Details**

- `-{3,}\n` - three or more `-`s and then a newline
- `([\s\S]*?)` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `\n-{3,}` - a newline and three or more `-` chars.